# Twilio Flex Plugin Upgrade to @twilio-labs/plugin-flex 5.1.3

Tags: twilio

When upgrading the Twilio CLI Flex-Plugin to 5.1.3, what is the proper way of handling upgrading an existing Twilio Plug-in Project which pre-dates 5.1.3?

Executing, `npm install @twilio/flex-plugin-scripts` throws a ton of warnings.

**Updating with more details**

Hi @philnash, lets say the Twilio CLI informs me of a new update to `@twilio-labs/plugin-flex`. If I do update this plug-in, when I run my existing Flex Plugins which used a previous version, I get a warning my plug-in was created with a previous version of the `@twilio-labs/plugin-flex`. What is the recommended way to handle this and update my Plugin?

Some examples when I tried to update the dependencies in the package.json are of the form (basically a ton of `peer dependency` warnings).

`@twilio/flex-dev-utils > axios-cache-adapter@2.7.3" has incorrect peer dependency "axios@~0.21.1"`

say when trying to update the `@twilio/flex-plugin-scripts` in my package.json.

Comment: Warnings are normally fine, though if you want to share them that could help. Are there errors?

Comment: @philnash - added some more content to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio support pointed me to this document

[Keeping Plugins Up-To-Date](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/plugins/updating)